# Rubber band not working on Gmail using Safari

Tags: macos, safari, gmail

Is it just me or the rubber band scrolling is not working on Gmail (I'm on Safari)? It works on any other site.

Comment: It's not just you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use a wrapper-div with `overflow: scroll` and `height: 100%`, which doesn't use the rubber-band-effect by default.